# findOneAndUpdate provides only a partial update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to update a database document, depending on user input, and whether it exists or not (and create it if not). The user can retrieve stock price of a company, and like it once.

```js
    async function run() {
      var price = await getPrice(query.stock);
      if (!price) {
        return res.json({ stockData: { error: "stock not found" } });
      }
      if (!Array.isArray(query.stock)) {
        MongoClient.connect(CONNECTION_STRING, function(err, client) {
          var db = client.db("mydb");
          db.collection("stock").findOne({ stock: query.stock.toUpperCase() }, (err, doc) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (!doc && !query.like) {
              return res.send({
                stockData: {
                  stock: query.stock.toUpperCase(),
                  price: price,
                  likes: 0
                }
              });
            }
            if (doc && !query.like) {
              return res.send({
                stockData: {
                  stock: query.stock.toUpperCase(),
                  price: price,
                  likes: doc.likes
                }
              });
            }
            if (!doc && query.like) {
              db.collection("stock").insertOne({
                stock: query.stock.toUpperCase(),
                likes: 1,
                ips: [req.ip]
              });
              return res.send({
                stockData: {
                  stock: query.stock.toUpperCase(),
                  price: price,
                  likes: 1
                }
              });
            }
            if (doc && query.like) {
              if (!doc.ips.includes(req.ip)) {
                db.collection("stock").findOneAndUpdate(
                  { stock: query.stock.toUpperCase() },
                  { $inc: { likes: 1 } },
                  { $addToSet: { ips: req.ip } },
                  { returnOriginal: false },
                  (err, updoc) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    return res.send("test");
                  }
                );
              }
              return res.send({
                stockData: {
                  stock: query.stock.toUpperCase(),
                  price: price,
                  likes: doc.likes
                }
              });
            }
          });
        });
      }
    }
```

My issue is with the findOneAndUpdate operation. It is supposed to increase the number of likes and  add user's ip to the array, so that they can't like it again. It does the former as it should, but the array remains unchanged. In fact, other manipulations with it bear no fruit either. What's more, the program never progresses to the callback, doesn't return "test" and doesn't allow me to access the update document updoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/), This is how you should be updating the document

```
 db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
   <filter>,
   <update>,
   {
     projection: <document>,
     sort: <document>,
     maxTimeMS: <number>,
     upsert: <boolean>,
     returnNewDocument: <boolean>
   }
)
```

So all the `Update` stuff should be in the second parameter, so update your code like this

```
db.collection("stock").findOneAndUpdate(
              { stock: query.stock.toUpperCase() },
              { $inc: { likes: 1 } , $addToSet: { ips: req.ip } },
              { returnNewDocument: false },
              (err, updoc) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                return res.send("test");
              }
            );
```

As I don't know about `returnOriginal` but I do know about the property `returnNewDocument` which by default is `false`, but if you want to mention it explicitly it's totally up to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate({...query}, {...operations}, { new: true })
```

I think this is for mongoose but you could also use `returnNewDocument: true`